# why position variable in TbExtendedGridView sortable is undefined

Tags: php, yii, yii-booster

I'm using TbExtendedGridView sorableRows, and when I replace some rows, javascript show's this error in log:

```
id: [object Object], position:undefined
```

this error even appears in source site:
http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/extended-grid.html

how can I fix this problem?